# Pass Javascript Variable into tracking statement

Tags: javascript, variables, double-click-advertising

I am trying to pass the variable name into the DoubleClick tracking snippet.
name is obtained from an array (output) and contains the right value.

```
var name = output[0];
```

Doubleclick states the following:

```
HtmlEnabler.getInstance().thevariable(“Your String”);
```

Here is what I've got

```
HtmlEnabler.getInstance().variablename(name);
```

It's not working.

I also tried:

```
HtmlEnabler.getInstance().variablename(+name+);
```

Comment: The format `HtmlEnabler.getInstance().variablename(name);` is correct and should be working. There is something else wrong. thevariable for example - does `variablename` exist - it should be `counter` for example? Any errors in console? What does "is not working" mean exactly?

Comment: You are correct  - they have not been set up in the doubleclick reporting side yet.

Comment: Where does `output` come from? How do you know that `name` contains the right value? Is `name` a global variable?